# Operational transformation and collaboration in real time

Tags: javascript, ajax, comet, collaboration

After reading this [post](https://drive.googleblog.com/2010/09/whats-different-about-new-google-docs.html) (probably, you can get the gist by looking at the images, no need to read the whole text), I'm having a hard time deciding at which point is needed the help of [comet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)) type technologies.
It looks to me (naively) that all of that can be accomplished by using ajax requests and a database to retrieve several versions. Is that true?.

Probably I'm missing something, so a clarification would be great.

**UPDATE:**
Given the helpful answer written by Andrew, saying that an ajax approach to this issue it is not timely, I was wondering why, that is, at which stage the response sent by the server to the client will produce a delay?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comet IS Ajax requests.

In order for the server to be able to push notifications to the users browsers(IE anytime you see the server sending a change in the diagrams), the user needs to have a connection with the server already. The method of maintaining that connection using ajax long polling or the like is what the term comet refers to.

Yes, you could implement this by sending an Ajax request every x seconds. But that is wasteful, and it is not timely.

**[Edit]**

When I say it's not timely, what I am saying is that, using an ajax call to update on an interval will have a delay of whatever that interval is.
The server CANNOT send an update to the client. It can only answer requests from the client. So if the server gets new information, it has to sit on it until all the clients come back and ask for an update. In a scenario like this people can edit the same information and commit it at the same time, which needs to be handled by the server, and which is what the article is addressing. Using a comet framework will just reduce the chances of this happening because the different clients will be better synced.

Comment: @Andrew: Thank you for your answer. I had in mind using an Ajax Push service (APE or pusherapp). That changes the way this can be implemented?. Obviously I don't want to send an ajax request every x seconds, instead, those requests should start when a user trigger certain action.

Comment: No, what APE or any other comet implementation will do is open a connection with the server when the user loads the page (or document in the articles case), and just sit there. When the user makes a change locally, it can be sent to the server using ajax, when a remote user makes a change, the server will complete that request that is sitting there and the local user will be updated. The article is not talking about this at all though, it is just explaining how to maintain the state of a document with asynchronous changes going on, it expects the communication to be implemented by the reader.

Comment: @Andrew: Right. I know the article doesn't refer to this, but I was wondering whether APE (for example) could be used to help in an implementation.

Comment: @Andrew: By the way, in order to receive a notification of your comment, please add a @[username] in your message :-)

Comment: @Robert (Happy :P) Well if that is the case then, Yes! APE would work very well in creating a real time multi user work environment.